# JPA auto_increment id for generated @ManyToMany join table

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-many, composite-key

If I have a bidirectional @ManyToMany relationship between two entities (ie `Student` and `Course`), JPA generates a join table, `student_id_course_id`, with a composite primary key of `(student_id, course_id)`. That all works fine.

But what if I had a whole heap of other tables that work off that key, for example, `course_assessment` and `course_result`, that looked like this:

```
course_assessment
  student_id
  course_id
  assessment_item_description
  grade

course_result
  student_id
  course_id
  overall_grade
```

I don't want to proliferate the composite key `(student_id, course_id)` through these tables. I'd prefer for `student_id_course_id` to have a single auto_increment id and then to use that in the `course_assessment` and `course_result` tables.

This seems like it would be a fairly common scenario in JPA, but I haven't been able to find out how to do it. How do other people typically approach this?

Answer (score 0):

This situation is in fact pretty rare, because if you need to have tables referencing the fact that a user is registered into a course (I'll call this a "registration"), then it probably means that this registration is an entity, holding information.

The many-to-many relationship thus becomes two one-to-many relationships:

- One student has many registrations
- One course has many registrations

The registration entity can be used to hold information (date of the registration, ...), and you may have other entities referencing the registration using a foreign key to its auto-generated ID.